# How to tell the difference between mineral spirits and isopropyl alcohol

Tags: identification

They are both clear liquids, so is there a fairly simple test to determine if a container has one or the other? Maybe by mixing a sample with another chemical and looking for a color change? Thanks!

Comment: And why not just *smell* it?

Comment: I try to avoid inhaling mineral sprits as much as possible. Even breathing in small amounts often can add up.

Comment: Good luck avoiding vapor inhalation while making some solubility test :/

Comment: If by mineral spirits you mean low boiling petroleum distillate, simply add a small amount to an equal amount of water. It will float and not dissolve; 2-propanol dissolves in water. If you mean something else please be specific.

Comment: Ya that's what Poutnik had as an answer. I don't know what kind of mineral sprits the  liquid is composed of so I can't be more specific. Luckily the question was answered with a possible solution before this question was closed,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Shake well a small sample with similar volume of water and let it stand. If a single phase has been formed, it is isopropyl alcohol. If liquid has formed two liquid layers, it is a mineral spirit.

Isopropyl alcohol is, similarly as ethanol, miscible with water in any ratio. Additionally, its smell reminds ethanol.

Mineral spirits, similarly as mineral  oils, are not miscible with water and their mutual solubility is minimal. Additionally, their smell may remind gasoline or some paint thinners/solvents.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, I'm going to try this out when I return to the lab.